# java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Request timed out to in gatling

Tags: scala, stress-testing, gatling

Hi i'm running concurrent users 200 over 200 seconds, when I execute same script after 2-3 sets I'm getting this error do i need to do some settings in gatling for example shareConnections  in conf file or its because server is not able to respond to more request.

```
class  LoginandLogout extends Simulation {

val scn = scenario("LoginandLogout")
        .exec(Login.open_login)
        .pause(Constants.SHORT_PAUSE)
        .exec(CommonSteps.cscc_logout_page)
    setUp(scn.inject(rampUsers(200) over (200 seconds))).protocols(CommonSteps.httpProtocol)
}
```

I'm using gatling 2.0.0-RC5 scala 2.10.2

Answer (score 1):

Why blame the messenger? If you have a request timeout, that's your SUT's fault. Load testing is not about trying to tweak the injector to get the best possible figures, but to find out possible performance issues. You've just found one.

Using shareConnections makes sense when you're trying to simulated Web API clients (like a program calling a SOAP or RESTful webservice). It doesn't if you're trying to simulate web browsers.

> I'm using gatling 2.0.0-RC5 scala 2.10.2

You really should upgrade! Just check [the release notes](https://github.com/gatling/gatling/milestones?state=closed) since then, if you're not convinced.